# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execute)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

On my discord bot, I am making a "nickname" command.
My code on the nickname.js:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });
module.exports = {
    name: 'nick',
    description: 'This command with change a users nickname.',
    execute(message, args){
        const memberToEdit = message.mentions.members.first();
        const newNickname = message.content.replace(`${prefix}changenick`, '').split(' ').pop().trim();
        memberToEdit.setNickname(newNickname);
        }
}
```

The error I get whilst trying to run the command:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execute')
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DiscordBot\main.js:79:36)
    at Client.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:26:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1137:20)

Node.js v17.4.0
```

My main.js file is the same as the rest of the commands which work fine...

```js
  if(command === 'nick'){
    client.commands.get('nickname').execute(message, args)
  }
```

I can't seem to understand why this command specifically just wont work.

Comment: I think you should probably follow the guide ~ [Creating commands](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/creating-commands.html#creating-commands)

Comment: @Phil I can't use that yet, those are slash commands and have no relation to my error.

Comment: I'm not a discord user or bot author so what's the difference between a command like in your question and a command from the documentation I linked? In any case, commands seem to require some form of registration via `client.command.set()` or `applicationGuildCommands()`. That seems absent from your code

Comment: @Phil On discord, theres 2 types of command. The first being a prefix command (the one I use). On a prefix command, the bot will look for a message which starts with a certain prefix. For example: "!". A Slash command is like an integrated command which works with discord. Example: "/nickname".

Comment: @Phil in my config.js file. const prefix = config.prefix;

Comment: I feel I'm missing something so sorry if it's obvious. Your `nickname.js` file has an export. Where is that used?

Comment: I think you forgot to add your commands to the `client.commands` collection. What do you get when you try `console.log(client.commands.get("nickname"))` ? Is it empty / null / undefined or do you get the command you created?

Comment: Use `client.commands.get('nick')` instead...............

Comment: I used @PLASMAchicken comment and made it into an answer. If it helped, please mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@PLASMA chicken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6258290/plasma-chicken) said, the command you created is called nick, not nick*name*. So change `nickname` to `nick` where you call the `execute` function. For example, something like this:

```js
if (command === 'nick') {
    client.commands.get('nick').execute(message, args);
}
```

**Hoped this helped!**